# is it possible to have a jquery ui progress bar inside a jqgrid cell

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, progress-bar

i see they have examples using a [jquery datepicker](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) but i wanted to see if you could stick a [jquery progress bar](http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/) inside a jqgrid cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at: [Display progress bar inside JQGrid](http://csharptechies.blogspot.com/2010/11/display-progress-bar-inside-jqgrid.html)

The idea is to pass some HTML inside the data, i.e.

> {"id":"1","cell":["1","Scott","US","<DIV class=progBar>10</DIV>"]},

and replace this HTML with a progressbar.
This works for me, at least as long as the jqgrid does not have a pager.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of. If you only need to display amounts in large increments (say 10% chunks) you can use images of progress bars as a workaround.